# Find the URL of an image in java using Selenium from any given website

Tags: java, image, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to using Selenium Web Driver, however I'm currently undergoing a project that would make me need to save an image of a person from a website using just their name. Many solutions I've found online don't seem to work at least in my case scenario. The main issue I need assistance with is singling out specific images from a webpage. For example if I were to use the link https://www.squarespace.com/about/team/ I would need to be able to download images, or at least get the link of an image of solely one person based on their name. Any information would help, thanks!

Comment: If you want to get the images automatically  by application then Selenium is not a choice for you, you need a crawler tool like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document) because Selenium only use for finding a element which you have already know it's address (css selector, xpath...).

Comment: @TuyenNguyen [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document) may be a better way but we can achieve that easily through Selenium-Java binding as well using the [Java Collection](https://www.javatpoint.com/collections-in-java) framework. You can refer my Answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You can use the following code block to retrieve the name of all the Team Members and the link of the image of solely one person based on their name:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

    public class Q44980374_url_of_an_image 
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.get("https://www.squarespace.com/about/team/");
            JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)", "");
            //Get the Name of the Members
            List<WebElement> team_member = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//main[@id='content']//div[@class='team-members']/div[@class='team-member']/div[@class='team-member-text']/h3"));
            List<String> mem_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (WebElement member:team_member)
            {
                    String memeber_name = member.getAttribute("innerHTML");
                    mem_name_list.add(memeber_name);
            }
            List<WebElement> team_member_images = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//main[@id='content']//div[@class='team-members']/div[@class='team-member']/div[@class='team-member-portrait']/img"));
            List<String> mem_image_list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (WebElement image_link:team_member_images)
            {
                    String memebr_image = image_link.getAttribute("src");
                    mem_image_list.add(memebr_image);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<team_member.size();i++) 
            {
                System.out.println(mem_name_list.get(i)+"'s image link is : "+mem_image_list.get(i) );
            }
        }

    }
```

The Output of this code block is:

```
Anthony Casalena's image link is : https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ta/5134cbefe4b0c6fb04df8065/9025/assets/pages/about/team/executive-team/anthony-casalena-300w.jpg
Nicole Anasenes's image link is : https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ta/5134cbefe4b0c6fb04df8065/9025/assets/pages/about/team/executive-team/nicole-anasenes-300w.jpg
Andrew Bartholomew's image link is : https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ta/5134cbefe4b0c6fb04df8065/9025/assets/pages/about/team/executive-team/andrew-bartholomew-300w.jpg
John Colton's image link is : https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ta/5134cbefe4b0c6fb04df8065/9025/assets/pages/about/team/executive-team/john-colton-300w.jpg
Raphael Fontes's image link is : https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ta/5134cbefe4b0c6fb04df8065/9025/assets/pages/about/team/executive-team/raphael-fontes-300w.jpg
David Lee's image link is : https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ta/5134cbefe4b0c6fb04df8065/9025/assets/pages/about/team/executive-team/david-lee-300w.jpg
Kinjil Mathur's image link is : https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ta/5134cbefe4b0c6fb04df8065/9025/assets/pages/about/team/executive-team/kinjil-mathur-300w.jpg
Roberta Meo's image link is : https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ta/5134cbefe4b0c6fb04df8065/9025/assets/pages/about/team/executive-team/roberta-meo-300w.jpg
Kris Passet's image link is : https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ta/5134cbefe4b0c6fb04df8065/9025/assets/pages/about/team/executive-team/kris-passet-300w.jpg
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: `"need to save an image of a person from a website using just their name"` I think that the question is only have the person name and want to get the image corresponding to the name. He does not have the xpath to get it.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen I think you missed out a portion of what OP was expecting as in `or at least get the link of an image of solely one person based on their name`. Moreover when the `url` is already retrieved downloading is just a step away only to pass the click(). Let me know if we are on the same page. Thanks